# Run TYPO3 Fluid on VueJS component

Tags: vue.js, typo3, fluid

I have a VueJS component and I'm trying to add translated text via Fluid tag.

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers">
  <h2><f:translate key="search.resultPage"/>"{{mutatedQuery}}".</h2>
</div>
```

The tags are displayed on frontend, but the `<f:translate>` tag is empty.

Comment: try to add the extensionName parameter as well in the f:translate tag. It might not know from which extension should TYPO3 get the translation from. Delete all Cache as well. If that is the answer just tell me to post it as an answer

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

### Assumed direction Fluid → Vue

Indeed that's tricky since Fluid does not support escape characters for inference literals like `{}` which are used in any other client-side frameworks like Vue or Angular as well.

| case | Fluid template | rendered output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `{{item.value}}` | ø |
| 2 | `{{ item.value }}` | `{{ item.value }}` |
| 3 | `{{<f:comment/>item.value<f:comment/>}}` | `{{item.value}}` |

- 1: empty string (we knew that already)
- 2: works, adding space between braces and variable name
- 3: works, since `<f:comment/>` breaks Fluid inline pattern (but it's "ugly")

### Assumed Direction Vue → Fluid

It is not possible to call Fluid (server-side rendering) from Vue (client-side template & document fragment).

### Alternative, combining both via slots

It is possible to use Fluid in the base template served by a web server and use slots to inject the content to Vue components, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html.

Main Fluid template:

```
<div
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers">

  <my-app>
    <template v-slot:resultPageLabel>
      <f:translate key="search.resultPage"/>
    </template>
  </my-app>
</div>
```

Vue `my-app` component template:

```
<h2>
  <slot name="resultPageLabel"></slot>
  "{{mutatedQuery}}".
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't succeed to integrate Fluid on Vue, I think that both have different rendering engines and can not be synchronize as I wanted.

I solved this issue by adding `<f:translate key="search.resultPage"/>` as a `data-attribute` on another tag(that is not rendered in vue) and get that translates on vue component.